# Browser doesn't send entire POST data to C socket server

Tags: c, linux, http, sockets, post

I've got a simple C socket server listening at `localhost:8080` that continuously `read`s from the client socket until it encounters `quit` at the end of the message.

I tested this on Chrome (Android) and Firefox (Android). I sent a `POST` request as follows:

```html
<form
    action="http://localhost:8080"
    method="POST" >
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000"/>
    Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File"/>
</form>
```

On the server side, I could only see that it recieved the request headers. No file data was recieved.

Req from Chrome:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 52
Cache-Control: max-age=0
sec-ch-ua: "Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"
Origin: http://localhost:5000
DNT: 1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Referer: http://localhost:5000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,bn;q=0.7
```

When I added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the above `form`'s attribute though, the full data and file with multiple boundaries was recieved.

Afterwards I tried the following POST with and without multipart:

```html
<form
    action="http://localhost:8080"
    method="POST" >
    <input name="test" value="foobar"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Results were same, only headers were recieved with urlencoded data. Full data was sent with multipart.

My question is why this is happening, and does the browser expect a response in the first case before it continues sending further data?

My aim is to recieve the POST data at once. Is that not possible?

On a side note, I noticed that after the multipart POST request, the request didn't end with two CR LFs, instead just one.

Edit: Just noticed that when I reload the browser it closes the connection and at that moment the remaining POST data shows up (without any CR LF ending after the POST).

### Serve code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int portno = argc == 2 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 8080;
    int srvfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    int option = 1;
    setsockopt(srvfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &option, sizeof(option));
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (bind(srvfd, (struct sockaddr*) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("server: error binding");
        exit(1);
    }
    listen(srvfd, 1000);
    printf("server: listening at port %d\n\n", portno);
    struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;
    socklen_t clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    int clifd = accept(srvfd, (struct sockaddr*) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    while (true) {
        char buffer[256];
        int n = read(clifd, buffer, 255);
        if (n == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "server: error: connection closed\n");
            exit(1);
        } else if (n < 0) {
            perror("server: error reading from socket");
            exit(1);
        }
        buffer[n] = 0;
        printf("%s", buffer);
        if (!strncmp(buffer, "quit", 4))
            exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, it sends the POST data. Are you sure that your server has received all the data? If there are not two CRLF at the end, then this isn't the end of the data. My crystal ball says the browser sends the full data but your server program doesn't print the full data because it is badly coded.

Comment: I've posted the server code with an edit

Comment: what if you call fflush(stdout); after printf?

Comment: ok, then that was the answer. easy problem...

Comment: I think you are right. Content-Length is 52 so the request is finished after CRLFCRLF and then 52 more bytes. No need for an *extra* CRLF.

Comment: that means there probably *are* two CRLFs after the request even though you said there was one. There must be two CRLFs after the last header and before the POST data.

Comment: i rechecked, and no the complete multipart data ended with just one CR LF, ofc the seperation b/w the headers and the data does have two CRLF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After printing some data, call `fflush(stdout);` to make sure it is not buffered.

There is not an extra CRLF after the end of the POST data. The server knows the end of the POST data because of the Content-Length header. Because the browser specifies `Content-Length: 52` the server knows the POST data is exactly 52 bytes.

Comment: although that does mean POST request is not ending with CR LF, otherwise printf would have auto flushed the buffer